# PHP Rewrite SEO friendly URL - Inside folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This a php mod rewrite related question

Background info :

I am using wordpress site in my root ( example.com)
I have a folder created under that called 'search-jobs', which has all the php code  ( example.com/search-jobs) I am not using wordpress for anything on this search page, but wanted to ensure  you have that info and if it impacts.

I am trying to rewrite the below URL :

```
http://example.com/search-jobs/?searchText=FACEBOOK+INC.&searchCity=Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode&searchYear=14&action=search&searchJobTitle=Enter+Job+Title+%2F+Role+Name
```

I have the below mod rewrite written in the .htaccess file, which is placed in the root folder, where wordpress is installed.

```
# BEGIN search Rewrite rules 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^company/([0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]+)$ /search-jobs/?searchText=$1&searchCity=$2&searchYear=$3&action=$4&searchJobTitle=$5 [NC,L]

</IfModule>

# END search Rewrite rules
```

Also, four of the variables typically have spaces as they are search strings. Not sure, if that is causing issues.

Below is the full Wordpress rewrite rule that excludes the folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(search-jobs|search-jobs/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I saw some wordpress rewrite rules in the .htaccess file, is that messing up my rewrite rules or am I doing something wrong ?   I am doing this for the first time. I have tried for couple of days on this reading many other, badly stuck. Any help would be great.

Comment: This is not a wordpress related question. I gave that info as an FYI. It is a pure PHP question with mod re-write.

Comment: Yes, the wordpress rewrite can mess with your current rule. Since you do not write what exactly happens, and how that differs from the expected behaviour, I can't help you much. Please include the wordpress rewrite rule in your question for completeness sake.

Comment: Yes Sumurai, I have added the wordpress mod rewrite rules in root .htaccess file.  This is driving me crazy :(

Comment: Make sure your rules are on top of wordpress rules, then you don't need to exclude `search-jobs`. And you don't need to do `([0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]+)`, you could `([^/]+)` instead. And can you explain bit more how wordpress messing with your rules?

Comment: Also you are telling here `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(search-jobs|search-jobs/.*)$` whenever url start with `/search-jobs` prevent wordpress rules, this will won't work because you've written that url must start with the `/company` which maps to `search-jobs*`.

Comment: mod_rewrite isn't related to PHP either, it's an Apache module. Fixed tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have root WP .htaccess like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|search-jobs(/.*)?)$ - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Then inside `/search-jobs/.htaccess` have code like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /search-jobs/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?searchText=([^\s&]+)&searchCity=([^\s&]+)&searchYear=(\d+)&action=([^\s&]+)&searchJobTitle=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?searchText=$1&searchCity=$2&searchYear=$3&action=$4&searchJobTitle=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. but for some reason, it is not working Anubhava. Am I missing anything. The query string parameters have spaces, do you think that is the issue ?

Comment: Well, I have replaced the code with your suggestion and it is not doing the re-write. I have done the phpinfo. Please check : http://redbus2us.com/h1b-visa-sponsors/

Comment: Well, I have replaced the code with your suggestion and it is not doing the re-write. I have done the phpinfo . http://redbus2us.com/h1b-visa-sponsors/tmp-index.php   ( as it is live site, I could not do the index.php )

Comment: Anubhava, but after I hit search button, isn't the URL supposed to be written in SEO friendly format. Also, the search results are coming up. Please advise.

Comment: This is the exact URL that I get when I hit search : http://redbus2us.com/h1b-visa-sponsors/?searchText=GOOGLE+INC.&searchCity=Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode&searchYear=14&action=search&searchJobTitle=Enter+Job+Title+%2F+Role+Name  and I want the URL to be like http://redbus2us.com/h1b-visa-sponsors/company/GOOGLE+INC./Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode/14/search/Enter+Job+Title+%2F+Role+Name    The whole idea is that, when user hits search, he should see the pretty url without the ampersands.

Comment: Thanks ! I have fixed that %2F now ( removed it in code so that it does not come as part of url parameter). Now URL after change : http://redbus2us.com/h1b-visa-sponsors/?searchText=GOOGLE+INC.&searchCity=Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode&searchYear=14&action=search&searchJobTitle=Enter+Job+Title . Can you please advise ?

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, it works with the URL. But when I re-submit it creates issues. Also the result seems all garbled out because of the CSS. Can we have the  URL to avoid 'company' in the re-written URL ?    Here is the appended URL http://redbus2us.com/h1b-visa-sponsors/company/GOOGLE+INC./Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode/14/search/Enter+Job+Title?searchText=facebook&searchCity=Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode&searchYear=14&action=search&searchJobTitle=Enter+Job+Title

Comment: Here is the ideal URL that I would like to have : http://redbus2us.com/h1b-visa-sponsors/GOOGLE+INC./Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode/14/search/Enter+Job+Title   I tried myself removing 'company' from the code you have given and it gives errors like [an error occurred while processing this directive]. Sorry for too many questions :)

Comment: Excellent ! Works like a charm ! You are the best. One final silly question. How can I replace the '+' symbols that are for white spaces in search string with '-' so that it looks nice. /GOOGLE+INC./Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode/14/search/Enter+Job+Title

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67797/discussion-between-anubhava-and-kumar).